# TypeError: sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels' when compiling CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, typeerror

I am getting a TypeError in Python during when compiling a convolutional neural network with `tensorflow`. I have tried updating `tensorflow`, but I am still getting the TypeError. This is the error message I get:

```
# Compiling CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=
['accuracy'])
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=
['accuracy'])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-003b5eeaec4a>", line 1, in <module>
  classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', 
  metrics=['accuracy'])

  File "C:\Users\Arunachalam\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-
  packages\keras\models.py", line 821, in compile
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Arunachalam\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-
  packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 860, in compile
    sample_weight, mask)

  File "C:\Users\Arunachalam\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-
  packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 459, in weighted
  score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)

  File "C:\Users\Arunachalam\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-
  packages\keras\losses.py", line 68, in binary_crossentropy
  return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)

  File "C:\Users\Arunachalam\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-
  packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2947, in 
  binary_crossentropy
  logits=output)

  TypeError: sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits() got an unexpected keyword 
  argument 'labels'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to reformat your question, fix some grammar, and to condense the error message. It might be helpful to post your full code that lead to the error, i.e. how did you initialize your classifier etc. Can you add that part of your code to the question? That would make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same TypeError when I used Tensorflow r0.11. After I upgraded Tensorflow to 1.3.0, the TypeError went away.